# Dynamically generated attribute accessors in Perl

Tags: perl, meta-programming

In my spare time I'm working at a perl library, which is the lightweight implementation of a package I did some time ago. In the previous iteration I used **Moose** as object-oriented framework, as suggested by many people on the Internet.

Later in time I realized how Moose was a total overkill for my use case (I'm not a big fan of the 8-hours dependencies setup time), and that's the reason why I went for a refactoring.

Suddenly I found myself to face a situation where I want something similar to what I used to have with Moose, but in a far simper way: I would like one of my modules to have simple setter/getter properties without manually defining all of them.

I came out with the following simple implementation, which seems to be quite effective:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

package Foo;

BEGIN {
    no strict 'refs';
    foreach my $mname (qw/bar baz/) {
        *$mname = sub {
            my $self = shift;
            if (@_) {
                $self->{$mname} = shift
            } else {
                $self->{$mname}
            }
        }
    }
}

sub new { bless {}, shift }
```

What do you think of it? Do you see any evident drawback? This is the code I used for testing it, and it seems to work just fine:

```
package main;

use feature 'say';

my $x = Foo->new();
for (1 .. 10) {
    $x->bar($_);
    say 'bar: ', $x->bar;
    say 'baz: ', $x->baz || '<none>';
    $x->baz($_);
}
$x->goat_cheese(3) # broken
```

Comment: Epilogue: I realized I don't really need it, so the day was saved. :D It was a bad case of overthinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I share @choroba 's opinion that this would be better implemented in either `Moo` or `Class::Tiny`.

Partly because your current design has a lot of different concerns in the same context.

For instance, if you wish to provide a default value for any of those accessors, you have a problem.

And your `new` can't help you if you pass the wrong keys.

What you're doing is probably fine for very tight, internal APIs, but you want a bit more rigour for public ones.

Class::Tiny and Moo both have an obvious path forward to adding defaults and default generators.

```
- use Class::Tiny qw( foo bar );
+ use Class::Tiny qw( foo ), { bar => sub { "default" } };

  use Moo;
  has 'foo' => ( is => 'rw' );
- has 'bar' => ( is => 'rw' );
+ has 'bar' => ( is => 'rw', default => sub { "default" } );
```

So by the time you roll your own equivalent utility, you've wasted a lot of time.

Additionally, generating mutable accessors is a very bad design default.

Mutating state is dangerous enough from inside an object, but doing it outside is typically asking for problems.

Comment: You hit a point: this is supposed to be an internal object, not exposed with outside. In the last case I tend to go with immutable objects, whenever possible.

Comment: For an internal API, you still might want a better constructor than you have. `bless { ref $_[1] ? %{ $_[1] } : @_[1..$#_] }, $_[0]` is a blob of magic I find myself using internally lots. At least that allows constructor-initalisation instead of lots of mutator methods.

Answer (score 4):

If [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose) is an overkill, you can try [Moo](http://p3rl.org/Moo) instead. There are some even simpler distributions like [Class::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Class::Tiny) or [Object::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Object::Tiny). They are probably better tested than your own solution as their user base is larger. They might also be faster (more optimized) and play well with inheritance and roles.